# how to translate strings via php from a module in prestashop?

Tags: module, translation, prestashop-1.6

I'm building a new module. As stated by the docs, I'm using the l() on a module's function, with a syntax like this:

```
$subtitles = array(
    '22' => $this->l('Per acquisti superiori ai 50€'),
    '23' => $this->l('30 giorni per sostituire o rendere')
);
```

I also can see, edit and save that sentences on tha backoffice translation page.

But if I check for ex. $subtitles[22], I always get the italian version, not the english one. Note that I checked also that $this->context->language->id corresponds to english.

So what's the problem here?

Comment: Is this code in a hook method?

Answer (score 0):

Ok no, THAT'S the right way. My problem was only that I was ehm.. choosing the wrong language to translate on the backoffice.. Pardon.